# Connection_timed_out when trying to connect to AWS EC2 tcp port (not rdp)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, connection-timeout

I'm trying to launch a socket server on Amazon EC2. It binds the socket to 0.0.0.0:5000 and then listens on this port, printing every incoming message

However, when I simply try to connect to ec2-18-x-x-x.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000 via Chrome, it throws an error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Of course, when I try to connect to it with a client using socket.connect(), a client is also unable to set up a connection.

I've already added the port to the security group inbound rules like that:

[image]

netstat -a shows that this port is open:
[image]

I use the public DNS IPv4 address, that is stated in instance description.

As I've successfully launched the server and tested netstat, it's obvious I can connect to EC2 using RDP.

Guided by [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout) troubleshooting manual, I've also checked the route table for subnet and ACL for subnet, but everything was OK.

What's the problem then?

Comment: I believe `netstat` is simply showing that some process is listening on that port, not that the port is "open". You still need to open port `5000` in the Windows firewall.

Comment: That helped, but can you answer the question so I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstat` is simply showing that some process is listening on that port, not that the port is "open". You still need to open port 5000 in the Windows firewall.